# Accidentally deleted Win 8 while installing Ubuntu 14

Tags: grub2, windows-8, uefi

My problem is that I accidentally deleted Win 8. But actually I don't need it and I don't want to buy Recovery disk. I need to install Ubuntu. So when I installing Ubuntu I just `Erase my disk and install Ubuntu`. The is happening at the end of installation. It's coping files, but at the end it's showing me a message

```
"We are sorry;the installer crashed. After you close the window, we'll allow you to
file a bug using..."
```

I don't know what to do. Help please :(

Comment: try to reinstall

Comment: I had this problem with my old desktop. My CD player was problematic and all of my tries went to trash. It is a Laptop or Desktop?

Comment: Just curious have you tried installing it a second time?

Answer (score -1):

From what information you provided you have three options:
1 Buy a new computer
2 Take your computer into a repair place
3 Take a USB stick to a friend with a computer and download Ubuntu into the USB stick then install on your computer.
Your online asking a question so you have something to get online with, can you download and write a file to an USB thumb drive from the unit your using to post this question?
If you have issues creating the USB linux bootable image:
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer/Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.8.exe

Comment: How can any of this help? The OP obviously already has some form of installation media, although he doesn't mention which type.

Comment: Not really, if he used Wubi or some other windows based tool he wouldn't have access to them after hosing his windows boot. But who knows, lack of info from the "OP" makes this a guessing game.